# aria-label extraction python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using xpath to scrape a webpage, however, there is a case in which I am not interested in the text but rather the content of the aria-label. Is there an easy way of scraping the aria-label value using xpath in python?

Comment: Can you add some input and expected output?

Comment: Input: span class: "y" aria-label: "x"; output: x while searching in class y

Comment: what have you tried so far? There are lots of ways to achieve this but we need to see where you are stuck and whether existing questions on SO haven't helped.